# Checking the checkbox of a Listview

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox

I'm using 2008 and .NET 3.5

I want to check the checkboxes of my ListView.

When I click on checkbox even if i click on 6th row first and 6th checkboxes are both checked, but if i click somewhere else, not on checkbox, the checkbox of this row is checked well.

How ever as I changed the filter s >= 0 to s > 0 (which was causing checking the first and the checkbox I clicked at same time the both) 
Now for checking the the first checkbox either I should double click the row or on the checkbox. The rest of the rows with single click works well.

The method that i use for checking the checkboxes when clicked somewhere else (not on checkbox) is :

```
        int s = 0;
        try
        {
            s = rapview.FocusedItem.Index;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (trsfLst && s > 0)
        {
            rapview.FocusedItem.Checked = !rapview.FocusedItem.Checked;
            rapview.FocusedItem.Focused = false;
            GetListSum(true);
            return;
        }
        if (rapview.SelectedItems.Count == 0 || trsfLst)
            return;
```

What I look for is there way to detect if I clicked on checkbox or somewhere else (on a row) ?

PS: trsfLst is a control that tells if i am in checking the checkboxes or update mode the rest of the method depends of trsfLst is true or false.

Comment: If you want to turn off the behavior due to which the check box gets ticked whenever user clicks anywhere in the row, then set the "FullRowSelect" property of the listbox control to False. I don't think there is any such option to identify whether user has clicked on the check box or on the row.

Comment: @Nirman I have no such problem. It works when I click on a row except first row I have to double click. But If I set  s >=0 my method checks the box of selected row and internal system checks the first box.
It's already FullRowSelect.